# memcpy, segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux

i have try to write this code, but i have found a problem with segmentation fault with memcpy ( i have try to see the code with debug)

```
        FILE *tp;
        int l = 0;
        while ((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, tp))) {
            // search equal sign
            char *equalsign = strchr(buffer, '=');
            l++;
            // search quote near value
            char *q1 = equalsign + 1;
            char *q2 = strchr(q1 + 1, '"');
            // extract name and value
            char* names = strndup(buffer, equalsign - buffer);
            char* values = strndup(q1 + 1, q2 - q1 - 1);
            memcpy(g_names,names,strlen(names));
            memcpy(g_values,values,strlen(values));
            free(names);
            free(values);
            }
```

with

```
const char* g_names[SIZE] = { 0, };
char* g_values[SIZE] = { 0, };
char buffer[MAXLINE] = {0,};
```

define as global. with the debug i have see that the problem is with memcpy (segmentation fault). anyone have a suggest?
Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: `memcpy(g_names,names,strlen(names));` Will **always** result in an unterminated string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two problems with your code: First, it is using `g_names` as the destination of `memcpy`, which copies the characters over the array of pointers. You should be copying to `g_names[l]` (assuming `l` was to be the index in the `g_names` array).

Second, your code is missing the actual allocation of `g_names[l]`, something like:

```
g_names[l] = malloc(strlen(names) + 1);
```

But since you're calling `strndup` anyway, you can simply store the result of that call into the array:

```
        // search for equal sign
        char *equalsign = strchr(buffer, '=');
        // search quote near value
        char *q1 = equalsign + 1;
        char *q2 = strchr(q1 + 1, '"');
        // extract name and value
        g_names[l] = strndup(buffer, equalsign - buffer);
        g_values[l] = strndup(q1 + 1, q2 - q1 - 1);
        l++;
```

Comment: it's perfect. i hope that it is not a stupid question. I have try all afternoon but i have not idea as fix it

Comment: @david Well, strictly speaking, SO questions shouldn't be about debugging specific code problems, but it's not *stupid*. Also, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Another issue is that `memcpy(g_names, `... is bad is that is scribbling all over some pointers